# how to fix an image size using cmb2 file type?

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am looking for how to fix an image size using cmb2 file type ?
It is working on back end right now but don't know how to fix the size of front end image.
If any one know how to fix it then please let me know.
Please let me know where to put the numerical value for front end image size.
Thank in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXE8r.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"?

Comment: How can I add an image size in px by using cmb2 file type ?